# Python 3 - How to create a code that allows the user to input both letters and numbers when entering their password

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I'm very new to python and have been assigned homework where my professor wants us to create a loop for when a user enters their pin (has to be numbers) to log in. The code has to allow only 3 attempts and has to lock out the user for 10 seconds (if PW is wrong) before looping back to allowing them to attempt to login in again.

So far I have been successful in creating a basic code for allowing 3 attempts.

```
original_pin = 1122

count=0

while count < 3:

    secret_pin = int(input('Enter Your Pin: '))

    if secret_pin == original_pin:

        print('DOOR UNLOCKED!!')
        break

    else:
        print('WRONG PIN!! (TRY AGAIN!)')
        count += 1
```

The issue I'm currently having is that if the user enters a letter, I get this error message (I entered "d") I'm not sure what to change in line 7 so that letters can be accepted as a input.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Indias/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/test.py", line 7, in <module>
    secret_pin = int(input('Enter Your Pin: '))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'd'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to change two things:

First, you'll need to store the pin as a string instead of an integer. You can do this by surrounding it in either single or double quotes:

```
original_pin = "1122"  # or '1122'
```

Second, you'll need to remove the `int()` surrounding `input()`, because that converts the user's input into an integer.

So if you wanted the pin to be `"1122d"`, the code would look like:

```py
original_pin = "1122d"

count=0

while count < 3:

    secret_pin = input('Enter Your Pin: ')

    if secret_pin == original_pin:

        print('DOOR UNLOCKED!!')
        break

    else:
        print('WRONG PIN!! (TRY AGAIN!)')
        count += 1
```

Edit re: "has to lock out the user for 10 seconds (if PW is wrong)"

You can accomplish this by calling `time.sleep(10)`, which causes the program to wait for 10 seconds before continuing. So the final code with that added looks like:

```py
import time  # so we can call time.sleep()

original_pin = "1122d"

count=0

while count < 3:

    secret_pin = input('Enter Your Pin: ')

    if secret_pin == original_pin:

        print('DOOR UNLOCKED!!')
        break

    else:
        print('WRONG PIN!! (TRY AGAIN!)')
        count += 1
        time.sleep(10)  # timeout for 10 seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the 'int(' on line 7, it's telling your program to only accept integers, and not accept letters, so you're throwing an error. That error is just telling you that letters aren't integers essentially.

```
original_pin = "1122d" #added a 'd' and made the variable a string!

count=0

while count < 3:

    secret_pin = input('Enter Your Pin: ') #removed 'int'

    if secret_pin == original_pin:

        print('DOOR UNLOCKED!!')
        break

    else:
        print('WRONG PIN!! (TRY AGAIN!)')
        count += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use error handling when inputting data as a user can any input the code may throw error and crash

```
original_pin = 1122
    
    count=0
    
    while count < 3:
        try:
    
            secret_pin = (input('Enter Your Pin: '))
        except ValueError:
            print("Enter Digits only")
    
        finally:
            if secret_pin == str(original_pin):
    
                print('DOOR UNLOCKED!!')
                break
    
            else:
                print('WRONG PIN!! (TRY AGAIN!)')
                count += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

don't convert your input into an integer. You can still do the same comparative statement with two strings, like you currently are with two integers.

```
pin_pass = input("Put pin in")

correct = "1234"
count = 0

if pin_pass == correct:
    print("Correct")
else:
    count += 1
    print("Wrong")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
original_pin = 1122

count = 0

while count < 3:

    secret_pin = input("Enter Your Pin: ")#remove int

    try:
        secret_pin = int(secret_pin)#convert input to int
    except:
        print("Enter Integer Value")#if not then print reason

    """Checking if secret_pin is int. and secret_pin == original_pin"""
    if isinstance(secret_pin, int) and secret_pin == original_pin:

        print("DOOR UNLOCKED!!")
        break

    else:
        print("WRONG PIN!! (TRY AGAIN!)")
        count += 1
```